# array_diff is working incorrectly on my arrays

Tags: php, arrays

```php
$data3 = 'primary_mobile_number, amount, new, hs_analytics_source_data_3';
$data4 = 'amount_in_home_currency, days_to_close, deal_currency_code, hs_acv, hs_all_assigned_business_unit_ids, hs_all_collaborator_owner_ids, hs_all_deal_split_owner_ids, hs_analytics_latest_source, hs_analytics_latest_source_company, hs_analytics_latest_source_contact, hs_analytics_latest_source_data_1, hs_analytics_latest_source_data_1_company, hs_analytics_latest_source_data_1_contact, hs_analytics_latest_source_data_2, hs_analytics_latest_source_data_2_company, hs_analytics_latest_source_data_2_contact, hs_analytics_latest_source_timestamp, hs_analytics_latest_source_timestamp_company, hs_analytics_latest_source_timestamp_contact, hs_analytics_source, hs_analytics_source_data_1, hs_analytics_source_data_2, hs_arr, hs_campaign, hs_closed_amount, hs_closed_amount_in_home_currency, hs_created_by_user_id, hs_date_entered_appointmentscheduled, hs_date_entered_closedlost, hs_date_entered_closedwon, hs_date_entered_contractsent, hs_date_entered_decisionmakerboughtin, hs_date_entered_presentationscheduled, hs_date_entered_qualifiedtobuy, hs_date_exited_appointmentscheduled, hs_date_exited_closedlost, hs_date_exited_closedwon, hs_date_exited_contractsent, hs_date_exited_decisionmakerboughtin, hs_date_exited_presentationscheduled, hs_date_exited_qualifiedtobuy, hs_deal_amount_calculation_preference, hs_deal_stage_probability, hs_deal_stage_probability_shadow, hs_exchange_rate, hs_forecast_amount, hs_forecast_probability, hs_is_closed, hs_is_closed_won, hs_is_deal_split, hs_lastmodifieddate, hs_likelihood_to_close, hs_line_item_global_term_hs_discount_percentage, hs_line_item_global_term_hs_discount_percentage_enabled, hs_line_item_global_term_hs_recurring_billing_period, hs_line_item_global_term_hs_recurring_billing_period_enabled, hs_line_item_global_term_hs_recurring_billing_start_date, hs_line_item_global_term_hs_recurring_billing_start_date_enabled, hs_line_item_global_term_recurringbillingfrequency, hs_line_item_global_term_recurringbillingfrequency_enabled, hs_manual_forecast_category, hs_merged_object_ids, hs_mrr, hs_next_step, hs_num_associated_active_deal_registrations, hs_num_associated_deal_registrations, hs_num_associated_deal_splits, hs_num_target_accounts, hs_object_id, hs_pinned_engagement_id, hs_predicted_amount, hs_predicted_amount_in_home_currency, hs_priority, hs_projected_amount, hs_projected_amount_in_home_currency, hs_read_only, hs_tcv, hs_time_in_appointmentscheduled, hs_time_in_closedlost, hs_time_in_closedwon, hs_time_in_contractsent, hs_time_in_decisionmakerboughtin, hs_time_in_presentationscheduled, hs_time_in_qualifiedtobuy, hs_unique_creation_key, hs_updated_by_user_id, hs_user_ids_of_all_notification_followers, hs_user_ids_of_all_notification_unfollowers, hs_user_ids_of_all_owners, hubspot_owner_assigneddate, primary_mobile_number, dealname, amount, dealstage, pipeline, closedate, createdate, engagements_last_meeting_booked, engagements_last_meeting_booked_campaign, engagements_last_meeting_booked_medium, engagements_last_meeting_booked_source, hs_latest_meeting_activity, hs_sales_email_last_replied, hubspot_owner_id, notes_last_contacted, notes_last_updated, notes_next_activity_date, num_contacted_notes, num_notes, hs_createdate, hubspot_team_id, dealtype, hs_all_owner_ids, description, hs_all_team_ids, hs_all_accessible_team_ids, num_associated_contacts, closed_lost_reason, closed_won_reason';
$data5 = explode(',', $data3);
$data6 = explode(',', $data4);

var_dump(array_diff($data5, $data6));
```

Why is it including `primary_mobile_number` in the difference when it is present in both arrays?

Comment: because there is a space after the comma. use `, ` as your separator.

Comment: Your `$data4` Array requires scrolling for 41 screens horizontally to read its content...! => This is not really "compatible" with providing a [mre]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you exclude by `,` it means all of the names in that string should be like this `name1,name2,name3` to work correctly but since you have a space after each comma `name1, name2, name3` instead you should exclude them by a comma flowed by a space. `,`

```php
$data5 = explode(', ', $data3);
$data6 = explode(', ', $data4);

var_dump(array_diff($data5, $data6));
```

Comment: Thanks, there was need of space after commas, it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can also use `array_map()` to apply `trim()` to every member of the arrays, like so:

```php
$data5 = array_map('trim', explode(',', $data3));
$data6 = array_map('trim', explode(',', $data4));

var_dump(array_diff($data5, $data6));
```

Which will account for the case that the whitespace may not always be consistent.